# Standard SQL (Bigquery) Deduplicate comma-separated lists

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table col with values like

```
"d,b"
"b,c"
```

and I want to aggregate it to say `"d,b,c"` and preferably sort it alphabetically to `"b,c,d"`.

Any idease please?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use `split()`:

```
with t as (
    select 'd,b' as col union all
    select 'b,c'
)
select string_agg(distinct el order by el)
from t cross join
     unnest(split(col, ',')) el;
```

That said, I would recommend that you use arrays instead of strings for storing such values.